# How do I convert a Python list of integers into a list of lists?

Tags: python, list

I have a list of elements like this:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

I need to convert them to a list of list since the output like this:

```
[[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

I have searched for some answers using the `map` function or using the `list` keyword but it's throwing an error saying the integer is not iterable.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: please give us some code you tried so far.

Comment: the map(lambda x: [x], l) is working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to build the list of lists:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4]
>>> [[x] for x in l]
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Or alternatively, `map`:

```
>>> list(map(lambda x: [x], l)) # list() not needed in Python 2
[[1], [2], [3], [4]]
```

Calling `list()` on a integer `x` won't work (as you state) because integers are not iterable (unlike, say, strings or tuples): you need to create a list containing `x` by writing `[x]`.

Comment: And even so, it won't do what is desired in the question when performed on strings or tuples.

Answer (score 0):

The NumPy function [atleast_2d](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_2d.html) can also be used, e.g:

```
>>> from numpy import atleast_2d
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> atleast_2d(a).T
array([[1],[2],[3],[4]])
```